# Snowflake script: accumulate result sets in for loop?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wrote a Snowflake script with a for loop to drop all "old" schemas in a database:

```sql
DECLARE
    rs RESULTSET;
    curs CURSOR FOR (
        select * from information_schema.schemata
        where last_altered < dateadd(day, -7, current_timestamp())
    );
BEGIN
    FOR record IN curs DO
        rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop schema if exists ' || record.schema_name || ';') ;
    END FOR;
    RETURN table(rs);
END;
```

I'm happy with this except that what it returns is only the result of the last query.

[image]

Of course this is expected because I'm not aggregating the results in `rs` inside the for loop, I'm merely overwriting `rs`.

I'm struggling to write something to store the results statuses in a table and return that at the end. Some help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using temporary table as an intermediate storage for DDL output:

```
DECLARE
    rs RESULTSET;
    curs CURSOR FOR (
        select * 
        from information_schema.schemata
        where schema_name NOT IN ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'PUBLIC')
          and last_altered < dateadd(day, -7, current_timestamp())
    );
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE PUBLIC.result_table(output TEXT);
    FOR record IN curs DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop schema if exists ' || record.schema_name || ';';
        
        INSERT INTO PUBLIC.result_table(output)
        SELECT "status"
        FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-1)));    
    END FOR;
    
    rs := (SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.RESULT_TABLE);
    RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

Output:

[image]